# MySql Error will not let me connect to DB

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-2002

(HY000/2002): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

Does anyone know of a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe [this](http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/212040) will help.

Are you sure mysqld is running and listening on port 3306?  `netstat -a` should tell you quickly.

Comment: Then start it.  What do you think you're connecting to?  Your client needs to talk to the listener on port 3306, and that's mysqld.

Comment: how can i get mysqld to run, it isn't running

Answer (score 0):

This may help.

http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/762/solve-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-tmpmysqlsock/